# Using Filters to Make Cells Delete Themselves

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, alamofire

Fairly new to coding!

I'm trying to create a user database with firebase that I'm able to filter in app. I figured the easiest way would be to toggle the filters on another view controller and then use if statements to have cells not meeting the filter criterium delete themselves. I'm hoping to have about 6 or so filters total, and I think this method is scalable.

I can't figure out how to get the cells to delete themselves.

This page just has a single filter on it. A prior view controller has a button that toggles "maleFilter" between 1 and 0. When male filter is 1, I want users that don't have "Male" as their gender to delete themselves. How might I got about doing that?

Thanks!

///Setup and grabbing the database from Firebase

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import Gloss

class UserTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var user: User?
var users: [User] = []
var myIndex = 0
var maleFilter: Int?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Alamofire.request("https://database.firebaseio.com/users.json").responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in

        if let usersDictionary = response.result.value as? JSON {

            for (key, value) in usersDictionary {

                if let usersDictionary = value as? JSON {
                    var user = User(json: usersDictionary)
                    user?.userKey = key
                    self.users.append(user!)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

///This is where I'm struggling
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

```
//maleFilter has its value toggled between 1 and 0 in a prior view controller
print(maleFilter)

//maleFilter == 1 represents the filter being toggled on
if maleFilter == 1 {
        if user?.userGender == "Male" {
            print ("male")
        } else {
```

I've tried this code that I found online and can't get it to work

```
            /*
             users.remove(at: indexPath)
             users.removeAtIndex(deletionIndexPath.row)
             tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath.row], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)
             */
```

I've also found this online and been unable to get it to work

```
      /*
let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (rowAction: UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: IndexPath) -> Void in
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
   */
 } else {
        print("Male filter not applied")
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I feel like the answer is probably really simple. Something like "                self.users.remove(at: indexPath) (which doesn't work"

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Any specific reason as to why you aren't using Firebase Library? Anyways, you have to not only delete the cells from the tableView , but also the datasource corresponding to that filter OR you have to use an `if` statement in the `tableViewDatasourceDelegate` functions to check that filter condition and call `_yourtableView.reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    filterArray = UsersArray.filter({ m in
m.UserGender.contains("Male")
})
```

Try this one , in result u get filter array only with Male.
Hope it will help you.